# UISegmentedControl programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a ViewController that contains:

- UISegmentedControl
- Container

[image: Image1]

I'm trying to change the selection programmatically when I arrive from another view.
I tried with:

```
if let previousSelection = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("SEGMENT_CONTROL") {
        segmentSaved = Int(previousSelection)!
    }

    if (segmentSaved == 0) {
        mySegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentSaved
    } else if (segmentSaved == 1) {
        mySegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentSaved
    } else if (segmentSaved == 2) {
        mySegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentSaved
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
```

It takes an int from memory and use it as index of the UISegmentedControl. It works but doesn't change the view in the container.

How can I do to change the container?

This is how it works:

```
let viewControllerIdentifiers = ["ViewController1", "ViewController2", "ViewController3"]

@IBAction func segmentController(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let newController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]))! as UIViewController
    let oldController = childViewControllers.last! as UIViewController

    oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    addChildViewController(newController)
    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame

    transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
            newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    })


}
```

Comment: `segmentController` is not a good name for the action method, because it sounds like it is a property. Use something like `segmentChangedAction` instead. Consider using a postfix like `Action` throughout your code for all action methods.

Comment: @meaning-matters thanks for the advice, I'll change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call function `self.segmentController(mySegmentControl)` after you change the selected index.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best!